# How to write JUnit for Spring WebFilter?

Tags: junit, spring-webflux

I have a `CustomWebFilter` class implementing `org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter` interface.

```
@Component
public class CustomWebFilter implements WebFilter {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, 
      WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
        if(<expression>){
            ServerHttpRequest mutatedRequest = exchange.getRequest()
                    .mutate()
                    .header("new-header-key", "new-header-value")
                    .build();

            ServerWebExchange mutatedExchange = exchange.mutate()
                    .request(mutatedRequest)
                    .build();
            return webFilterChain.filter(mutatedExchange);
        }
        return webFilterChain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

As the method `filter` return type is `Mono<Void>`, how I can verify the change in request by writing JUnit test?

Comment: Mock a ServerWebExchange and WebFilterChain, pass them into your method, then validate them after.

Comment: If all you want to do is unit test, then @123 is absolutely correct, you have to mock those parameters; however, if you want to test in a bigger flow, you know like integration testing, you can use [WebTestClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/reactive/server/WebTestClient.html).  Also, you can follow the examples [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-filters)

Comment: Solution given by @123 perfectly worked for me. Thanks